# Split up user creation and invitation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I have an app where the admin invites new users with devise_invitable. This works fine, but I want to split things up. First I want to create the user and then later on I want to be able to invite them. How can I split up these actions?

Comment: If you create them first, what are you inviting them to do exactly? Inviting them to confirm their account? Or set their password? Would they have the option to refuse and thereby delete their account? Why do you need the invite/create order to be reversed exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `skip_invitation` option when using `invite!` to skip sending the actual invitation.

```
User.invite!(:email => "new_user@example.com", :name => "John Doe", :skip_invitation => true)
# the record will be created, but the invitation email will not be sent
```

You can then send the invitation by:

```
user = User.find(42)
user.deliver_invitation
```

https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable